# App crashed when EditText addTextChangeListener is called

Tags: android, android-edittext, fatal-error, addtextchangedlistener

On entering new input in the EditText , it crashes and closes the app

I am not able to figure out the reason for the crash : 
Below is my code which i have tried so far :

Note : the Created "HelperMethods" had been tested and doing it's job

```
    // get the entered A.R.D from user
    final EditText A_R_D_EditText = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A_R_D_Value);
    A_R_D_EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            charSequence = Double.toString(Last_ARD_input_value);
            A_R_D_EditText.setText(charSequence);
            ;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                // check is a valid number
                double number = Double.parseDouble(charSequence.toString());
                if (HelperMethods.check_valid_number(number, 1)) {
                    A_R_D_value_deci = number;
                    A_R_D_value_degree = HelperMethods.convert_to(number, 1, 0);
                    A_R_D_value_mils = HelperMethods.convert_to(number, 1, 2);
                    Last_ARD_input_value = number;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), " Please enter a valid number ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), " Please enter a valid number ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // set A_R_D_value_degree
            TextView A_R_D_degree_textview = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A_R_D_Value_degree);             A_R_D_degree_textview.setText(Double.toString(A_R_D_value_degree));
            // set A_R_D_value_mils
            TextView A_R_D_mils_textview = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.A_R_D_Value_mils);
            A_R_D_mils_textview.setText(Double.toString(A_R_D_value_mils));

        }
    });
```

Comment: I think is this line `A_R_D_EditText.setText(charSequence);`

Comment: What I think is recursion you edit your `EditText` constantly.

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)

Comment: Is because you can't edit double time. In others words when you call this line you start again the `TextChangedListener` you do an infini loop

Comment: mmmm, you mean i can only use "A_R_D_EditText.setText" only one time in any one of the overideed  methods of the addTextChangeListener

Comment: you are right ,  thanks for helping